# Customize table view multiple selection checkmark

Tags: ios, tableview

I learned from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) that how to enable table view multiple selection. But how can I customize this? How can I replace those default views with my own, as shown in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found my own solution: changing the `auto layout constraints`.

My table view cell is a custom cell, in it I need to shift all the views to the right to show the selection indicator, so originally I put an customized indicator behind my custom views, then I setup 2 methods in my custom cell subclass to update the constraints of my view, to reveal the indicator underneath.

They look like this:

```
// in the cell subclass

- (void)showSelectionIndicator {
  self.imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 50.f;
}

- (void)hideSelectionIndicator {
  self.imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 15.f;
}
```

The `imageViewLeadingConstraint` is simply a leading constraint that determines the position of all my views in the cell.

Then, in the view controller, I manage the selecting status and the selected indexPaths myself. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I would additionally setup the cell like this:

```
// ... normal cell set up
if (self.isSelectingDownloads) {
  [cell showSelectionIndicator];
} else {
  [cell hideSelectionIndicator];
}
// return cell
```

I'll also have a method to toggle the selection status:

```
- (void)toggleDownloading {
  self.isSelectingDownloads = !self.isSelectingDownloads;

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This makes it all work. By calling `toggleDownloading`, the  views in the cell shift to the right as expected. Of course, I also need to do some logic in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to manage selection.

Answer (score 1):

A `UItableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView`, so you can call `addSubview` an add a `UIImage` view on each cell, or you can create your own UITableViewCell Class!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but those views (in the red circle in the image) are not under my control, they appear when the table view goes into editing mode, no matter it is a system style cell or custom cell.

Comment: You don't need to use those views, you can create your own custom cells and add whatever you like to them.

Comment: I see what you mean. That is how I got my solution - using custom views in the cell and move them by changing the autolayout constraints, the table view needs not to go into editing mode. Cheers.